# Differences in asp.net 2.0 lifecycle events and asp.net 3.5 lifecycle events

Tags: asp.net

Please can anyone direct me to links that will give me a detail of what has been added or removed in the lifecycle events from asp.net 2.0 to asp.net 3.5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The big change in lifecycle events was been 1.0 and 2.0, I don't think anything changed between 2.0 and 3.5. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx and use the 'other versions' link at the top of the page to do comparisons

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET 3.5 still uses the ASP.NET 2.0 DLL's, so nothing changed.  It wasn't until ASP.NET 4.0 did they update the System.Web DLL's, but nothing changed in 4.0 either.